# Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, equivalent

I am building a small app which captures mouse clicks. I wrote the prototype in jQuery but, since it is a small app focusing on speed, embedding jQuery to use just one function would be an overkill.

I tried to adapt this example from [JavaScriptKit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml):

```
document.getElementById("alphanumeric").onkeypress=function(e){  
    //blah..blah..blah..  
}
```

but it didn't work when I tried this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("x").onclick
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Say you have a list of p tags you would like to capture the click for the `<p>` tag:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) { 
    p[i].onclick = function() { 
        alert("p is clicked and the id is " + this.id); 
    } 
}
```

Check out an example here for more clarity:
http://jsbin.com/onaci/

Answer (score 12):

In your example you are using [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) method, which returns you an *array* of DOM elements. You could iterate that array and assign the `onclick` handler to each element, for example:

```
var clickHandler = function() {
    alert('clicked!');
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); // All divs

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it looks a little bit like you miss more than just the click function of jQuery. You also miss jquery's selector engine, chaining, and automatic iteration across collections of objects. With a bit more effort you can minimally reproduce some of those things as well.

```
var myClickCapture = function (selector) {
    var method, name,iterator;
    if(selector.substr(0,1) === "#") {
       method = "getElementById";
       name = selector.substr(1);
       iterator = function(fn) { fn(document[method](name));  };
    } else {
       method = "getElementsByTagName";
       name = selector;
       iterator = function(fn) { 
          var i,c = document[method](name);
          for(i=0;i<c.length;i++){
             fn(c[i]);
       };
    };
    myClickCapture.click = function (fn){
         iterator(function(e){
            e.onclick=fn;
         })
    } 

    return myClickCapture;

}
```

I haven't tested the code, but in theory, it gets you something like this:

```
myClickCapture("x").click(function(e){ alert("element clicked") });
```

Hopefully this gives you a sense of the sorts of things jquery is doing under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will save this down for my future developments.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("x")
```

returns an array of elements having the tagname 'x'.

You have to right event for each element in the returned array.