# Onclick event for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have more than one `<span>` with `class="section_title"`, I want to set up a unique event listener for all of them which runs a function onclick. How can I do this? (preferably without jQuery)

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: And how do I do this with class?

Comment: If you want to know how to select elements by class and add handlers, first search StackOverflow and Google. There's plenty of information already available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163073/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquery-click

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I don't know jQuery, so it's not the same question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var f = function(){
    // do something
}
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("section_title");
for (var i=0, len=elems.length; i < len; i++) elems[i].onclick = f;
```

Or for broader compatibility, use `.querySelectorAll()`, which takes a CSS type of selector.

```
var f = function(){
    // do something
}
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".section_title");
for (var i=0, len=elems.length; i < len; i++) elems[i].onclick = f;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   <span class="yourClass"/>
   <span class="yourClass"/>

   var spanSelector= document.querySelectorAll('.yourClass');//work in all browser

    for (var i = 0, i<  spanSelector.length;  i++) {
        spanSelector[i].onClick= yourFn// where yourFn is function name that will be colled on click of span.
    }
```