# Using addEventListener to show tabs

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm not sure how I can test if this is working, so any help is much appreciated. I'm trying to get a function to invoke once an element with a particular class is clicked.

The function will decipher which of the elements with the chosen class has been clicked and make changes to it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent").addEventListener('click', 
showTab);

function showTab(){
    if(this === this.id){
        this.className += "active";
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure addEventListener draws in information with it which means I can use the `this` keyword...?

Comment: you cannot add an event listener to a node collection and `this === this.id` will never evaluate to true.

Comment: Hi Jonas. Would I be able to put the tapContent inside a var and add an event listener to that? ....Guess I'll think of something else to help with the function.

Comment: Can you explain what you want when you did `this == this.id`

Comment: Sounds like you want something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163073/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquery-click).

Comment: I was looking to get an output of true. Writing out the description of how I wanted it to work for you made me realise why it wouldn't work. I guess I was looking for something such as...If the element that was clicked has the same id as one of the tabContent's then add the class 'active' to it.

Comment: Chris W response seems to be what I'm after, I'll try this, thank you.